# Unity Code not working as indented, Sometimes a Glitch occurs

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class JamesController : MonoBehaviour {

public static JamesController instance;

public GameObject particle;

[SerializeField]
public float speed;
bool started;
bool gameOver;
public Rigidbody rb;
Animator anim;

void Awake()
{
    if (instance == null)
    {
        instance = this;
    }
}

void Start()
{
    rb = this.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    anim = this.GetComponent<Animator>();
    started = false;
    speed = 7;
}

void Update()
{

    // if (!started)
    // {
    //     if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    //     {
    //         rb.velocity = new Vector3(speed, 0, 0);
    //         started = true;

    //         GameManager.instance.StartGame();
    //         anim.SetTrigger("Start");
    //     }
    // }

    if (rb.position.y < 0.45 && !gameOver)
    {
        gameOver = true;
        rb.velocity = new Vector3(0, -25f, 0);

        Camera.main.GetComponent<CameraFollowJames>().gameOver = true;
        Camera.main.GetComponent<CameraFollowAJ>().gameOver = true;
        Camera.main.GetComponent<CameraFollowRemy>().gameOver = true;

        GameManager.instance.GameOver();
        // CancelInvoke("IncreaseSpeed");
    }

    if (started)
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) && !gameOver)
        {
            SwitchDirection();
        }

        // InvokeRepeating("IncreaseSpeed", 0.1f, 1f);
    }
}

public void Started()
{
    if (!started)
    {
        started = true;
        rb.velocity = new Vector3(speed, 0, 0);

        GameManager.instance.StartGame();
        anim.SetTrigger("Start");
    }
}

void SwitchDirection()
{
    if (rb.velocity.z != 0)
    {
        rb.velocity = new Vector3(speed, 0, 0);
        transform.Rotate(0, 90, 0);
    }
    else if (rb.velocity.x != 0)
    {
        rb.velocity = new Vector3(0, 0, speed);
        transform.Rotate(0, 270, 0);
    }
    else if (rb.velocity == Vector3.zero)
    {
        rb.velocity = new Vector3(speed, 0, 0);
    }
}

void OnTriggerEnter(Collider col)
{
    if (col.gameObject.tag == "Diamond")
    {
        GameObject.Find("ScoreManager").GetComponent<ScoreManager>().score += 3;
        GameObject.Find("ScoreManager").GetComponent<ScoreManager>().diamondCount += 1;
        GameObject part = Instantiate(particle, col.gameObject.transform.position, particle.transform.rotation) as GameObject;
        Destroy(col.gameObject);
        Destroy(part, 1f);
    }
}

// void IncreaseSpeed()
// {
//     speed = speed + 0.00005f;
// }
```

}

The switch direction should work properly according to my theory, but it sometimes glitches.
See the Video below:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1eYY2GYYZASXukg9RARzNQYlk1q2zwcBV/view?usp=sharing

Comment: by glitch you mean that the cahracter does not turn when you expect him to, correct?

Comment: Actually it turns in the wrong direction, that is the glitch

Answer (score 0):

Might be easier to just use predefined rotations and velocities for this than use the additive transform.Rotate.

```cs
public class JamesController : MonoBehavior
{
    public Direction[] directions;
    public int directionIndex = 0;
    
    void Start(){
        SetDirection(directionIndex);
    }

    void FixedUpdate(){
        rb.velocity = directions[directionIndex].velocity;
    }

    void SetDirection(int index){
        directionIndex = index;
        rb.velocity = directions[directionIndex].velocity;
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(directions[directionIndex].eulerDirection);
    }

    void SwitchDirection()
    {
        directionIndex += 1;
        if(directionIndex >= directions.Length)
            directionIndex = 0;
        
        if(directionIndex < 0)
            directionIndex = directions.Length - 1;
            
        SetDirection(directionIndex);
    }
}

[System.Serializable]
public class Direction {

    public Vector3 velocity;
    public Vector3 eulerDirection;
}
```

Comment: Well I solved the issue, just used bool instead of that If else statement which determined the direction.

Comment: That works as well, I however recommend setting the rotation instead of using rotate in this case. If not for anything else then to avoid any drift due to floating point errors and whatnot since transform.rotate is additive.

Comment: Hmm, That's a great idea, I will definitely try that out.